# cygwin - cannot execute binary file

Tags: cygwin, variable-assignment

I am trying to run these two .data files from my c++ code for my assignment. I have been provided with all the files and are meant to only implement a few functions for the program (everything should be able to compile running the make command).

I used to run a MAC and only just started using windows (win 7) because work gave me a free laptop. Anyways...I installed cygwin, added the gcc-c++ compiler, gdb and make packages to my cygwin. But when i run the command `./file ./data` it comes up with:

```
bash: ./file: cannot execute binary file
```

is there a certain package or something I am suppose to install? Please note, that ./data is the folder that holds my two .data files, `file1.data` and `file2.data`

compiled by"

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -c file.cpp
g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -c file-test.cpp
g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -o file file.o file-test.o
```

Comment: Did you chmod it? Try `chmod +x ./file` first. I'd just install Ubuntu or something and do you development there. Cygwin is not perfect, and you'll run into lots of issues quickly.

Comment: No need to install Ubuntu, you could just run a virtual machine.

Comment: ./file assumes that file is in your current working directory ... confirm if that is the case.

Comment: ive tried `chmod +x ./file ./data` and it comes up with noting

Comment: yeah its in the same directory, i ran `make` and then compiled the object it gave me which was `file`

Comment: How did you create `./file` ? Did you compile a program, e.g. `gcc -Wall file.c -o file` ?

Comment: `g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -c file.cpp
g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -c file-test.cpp
g++ -Wall -Werror -02 -o file file.o file-test.o`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start by using the `file` command to see what type of binary file you have:

```
file ./file
```

If it is not an executable, that is a problem. If it is an ELF executable then it is probably intended to run on Linux, not on Windows. For example compare the output with this command:

```
file /bin/bash
```

which should tell you:

/bin/bash: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows

Now try this command:

```
file /cygdrive/c/windows/write.exe
```

Which says the following:
/cygdrive/c/windows/write.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows

I ran this on a 64-bit Windows 7 installation, which is why it says x86-64. Even though this is a Windows GUI app totally unrelated to cygwin, I can still run it by the command:

```
/cygdrive/c/windows/write
```

You really did not explain how you got this binary file named `./file`. Is it possible that it is an object file from compiling that you have not yet linked into an executable? If you have a Makefile, why not post its contents?

Comment: Are you sure that was -02 and not -O2. If so, change it to the letter O and try again.