# Can't Run GCC on Cygwin Windows

Tags: gcc, compilation, cygwin

I'm trying to compile some C files on my Windows. (already tried to change permissions with chmod)
Here is the error i'm getting:

```
$ gcc -c hello.c hello.o
bash: /usr/bin/gcc: cannot execute binary file
```

I have checked, and this is my PATH on the environment variables:

```
C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin
```

When I type only `gcc` i'm getting the same error, instead of getting a Missing arguments error.

the `which` command responds as:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

So, i'm stuck here. 
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: [What does `file /usr/bin/gcc` print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970962/cygwin-cannot-execute-binary-file)

Comment: $ file /usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc: data

Comment: Remove and reinstall cygwin.

Comment: Done that already :(

Comment: Don't know what are your requirements, but trying out MinGW or *nix on a VM might be a simpler solution compared to understanding what went wrong with your cygwin install.

Comment: I can't run it on VM. 
We have to work on cygwin from the windows, to run XV6 
Any other ideas?

Comment: You have a cygwin installation problem, i.e. it's broken. Either you are installing cygwin incorrectly, or the cygwin installer isn't working for you.